# Not able to set another image below first image in linear layout

Tags: android, crash, android-linearlayout, inflate-exception

I'm working on some project and i use linear layout and set image and text in it. after ending first linear layout i want another linear layout and set image. But i'm setting image my app keep on crashing.
This is Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".guidance_new"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_animation"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/hanging_lamp"
        android:src="@drawable/bulb1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="100W Bulb"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Price:100/. Voltage:220V-240V ."
            android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
            android:textStyle="bold"


            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>


        /////// layout is set here



    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/chandlier"
        android:src="@drawable/chandelier"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="Chandlier"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>




    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is mainlog:**

06-09 18:26:34.348 23904-23904/com.example.animation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.animation, PID: 23904
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.animation/com.example.animation.guidance_new}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class ImageView

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.animation.guidance_new.onCreate(guidance_new.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.animation.guidance_new.onCreate(guidance_new.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.animation:drawable/chandelier" (7f060064) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060064 a=-1 r=0x7f060064}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2617)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2555)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.animation.guidance_new.onCreate(guidance_new.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

06-09 18:26:34.357 23904-23927/com.example.animation V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress

Answer (score 0):

Resource that you are trying to display in ImageView (chandelier) is invalid. 
You can read in your log that: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.animation:drawable/chandelier" (7f060064) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060064 a=-1 r=0x7f060064}` Check if path to the file is correct and try to display other image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".guidance_new"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_animation"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/hanging_lamp"
            android:src="@drawable/bulb1"/>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="100W Bulb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Price:100/. Voltage:220V-240V ."
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                android:textStyle="bold"


                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
        </LinearLayout>





        /////// layout is set here



    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/chandelier"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/chandlier"
            android:src="@drawable/bulb1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Chandlier"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```